# Strange behavior with iPhone 11 Max Pro and Wi-Fi

Tags: iphone, wifi

When I try to connect to WiFi, the Wi-Fi icon in top right corner disappears immediately and after that, some applications have a full connection like Chrome and Safari; some have partial connection like Facebook and Instagram for content but not for messaging; while some don't have any connection at all like Viber, Messenger, Whatsup, and Apple notifications.

All settings have been reset, tried on multiple routers, software updated to latest versions. I even reinstalled apps, but problem stays.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Have you tried resetting the iPhone? Also, when the icon disappears, is WiFi still showing up as turned on in Control Center?

Comment: Yes in control center it is showed that is turned off. I reseted multiple times, reseted all settings multiple times, updated to latest ios, reseted routers multiple times on multiple places, problem stays.